# Wife involved in car accident, minor injuries, not her fault, driver failed to yield

Tags: united-states, legal-terms, common-law, accident

my wife was in a car accident back in March of this year. She was in a 2001 Toyota Sequoia when a car failed to yield and turned left in front of her causing the accident. The air bags did deploy and the car was totaled.

She went to emergency room because here neck, shoulder and back were sore just to make sure she was ok. We contacted an attorney and they had her go to several chiropractor sessions.

The car was in decent condition before the accident, priced at around $7,000

Their insurance company gave us around $6000.
They gave us $500 for car rental in the interim.

The attorney got back to us last week and said we were awarded $4500 in medical compensation.
What do I need to do at this point? How do verify amount is correct?

We had to purchase a car lower than what we had, although newer and more expensive, so now we have a car payment that we didn't have before.

Comment: If you have a question about your legal case, I would humbly submit that you would get more reliable information by directing it to your lawyer, rather than a bunch of random yoohoos on the Internet.

Comment: You need to hire a lawyer.

Comment: I did hire a lawyer, who you consider hiring another one

Answer (score 2):

We can't, in general, answer questions that ask "what should I do?"

The insurane company is (almost surely) offering a **settlement**. This will be less than you might possibly get after  a trial, but you don't have the uncertainty of a verdict that might be smaller, nor the delay, stress, and costs of a legal case.

You could attempt to negotiate for a higher payment, probably through your attorney. Or you could take the matter to court. Your attorney could advise you on the costs, risks and possible benefits of either course. We cannot.

One option would have been to buy an older used car, of similar value to your previous var.